# c# A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields, methods or statements [C#]

Tags: c#

This is my code - I get this error

> A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields, methods or statements [C#]

I am not using any `int` variable in the namespace, instead it is in class, still I get this error, don't know how to resolve it.

```
using System;
    
namespace Myproject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float [] a = { 10,11,12,13,14,15 } ;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Array.Reverse(a);

            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must have another file in your project or some other code you're not seeing, because the syntax of what you have posted is correct.

Comment: Even i have created new files on visual code but again same error. Confused AF!

Comment: You do want Program and Main to both be public. That might help.  Here's a Fiddle of the code and it runs fine. https://dotnetfiddle.net/mCGZsB

Comment: Strange as it is running on dotnetfiddle correctly but on visual code it is not.

Comment: Seems obvious, but have you tried restarting the editor? Failing that try cleaning your solution and rebuilding it, can sometimes resolve odd issues of code appearing to 'not work' in the editor/IDE.